# Failed to start HTTP/2 Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-15.10, http2

I have a serious problem here. After messing up with my server (I installed ntop and ntopng which had a port error because port 3000 was binded by nghttpx) I uninstalled ntop and ntopng and then at the next reboot I get the error:

> winpack.cf systemd[1]: Starting HTTP/2 proxy...
>
> winpack.cf nghttpx[768]: 14/Apr/2016:21:07:16 +0300 PID768 [WARN]
>   shrpx_config.cc:2012 frontend-no-tls: deprecated.  Use no-tls keyword
>   in frontend
>
> winpack.cf nghttpx[768]: [FATAL] Too few arguments (shrpx.cc:2060)
>
> winpack.cf nghttpx[768]: 14/Apr/2016:21:07:16 +0300 PID768 [WARN]
>   shrpx_config.cc:2016 backend-no-tls: deprecated.  backend connection
>   is not encrypted... backend-tls
>
> winpack.cf nghttpx[768]: Usage: nghttpx [OPTIONS]... [
>   ]
>
> winpack.cf nghttpx[768]: A reverse proxy for HTTP/2, HTTP/1 and SPDY.
>
> winpack.cf systemd[1]: nghttpx.service: Control process exited,
>   code=exited status=1
>
> winpack.cf systemd[1]: Failed to start HTTP/2 proxy.
>
> winpack.cf systemd[1]: nghttpx.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> winpack.cf systemd[1]: nghttpx.service: Failed with result
>   'exit-code'.

By the way, you can do testing at my domain (winpack.cf), but the weird is that Apache correctly serves HTTP/2 without nghttpx!

What's going on here? How can I fix the above error? I can provide any additional log you may need.

Comment: No help here? Why not?

Comment: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://serverfault.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Seems `nghttpx` was updated. See https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttpx-howto.html#migration-from-nghttpx-v1-8-0-or-earlier

Comment: @FedericoSierra But I think Apache is handling nghttpx alone, so since I also updates Apache to the latest stable version, shouldn't it coordinate? Anyway, how can I find the nghttpx parameters or the command that runs on boot time?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you think of any reason why this daemon fails? Maybe if I provide you with some log files?